# SQL BACKUP Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

how can i backup data from a query with MSSQL. I think about something like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE 'sourceDB' 
Select * from Table1 where Day = '12.01.2010';
TO DISK = 'F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Backup\sourceDB.bak' WITH FORMAT
```

Thank you for your support!

Cheers

Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to **Management Studio**, you can save query results to a file quite easily:

- Open a query window. One way to do
  this is by right-clicking on the
  database name in the Object Explorer.
- You might want to write the query and
  run it there first, to test that it
  is producing the desired results.
- When you are ready to run the query and save it to file, **on the menu choose Query, then Results To, and finally Results to File**.
- Now, when you run the query (F5), you will get a dialog box to indicate the filename and folder to save the data.

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 4):

The backup command is used to backup entire databases into a proprietary format.

To store the result of a query in a file, check out the `bcp` utility.  This allows you to run a query and store the result in a text file.  One example:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM Northwind.dbo.Customers" queryout "c:\text.txt" -c -T -x
```